# C++11 : type name for std::mem_fn

Tags: c++, c++11

`auto` is good, but I need to declare a member in a class, not a variable in the stack.

`decltype` works, but just somehow looks weird

```
class Automation {
    void _init_state(int);

    decltype(std::mem_fn(&Automation::_init_state)) next_state;
};
```

`std::function` seems to work too, but there is a slight difference from pure member function

```
class Automation {
    void _init_state(int) {}
public:
    decltype(std::mem_fn(&Automation::_init_state)) next_state;
    std::function<void(Automation&, int)> next_state_fn;

    Automation()
        : next_state(&Automation::_init_state)
        , next_state_fn(&Automation::_init_state)
    {}
};

int main()
{
    /* on ubuntu, x64 */
    std::cout << sizeof Automation::next_state << std::endl; /* 16 */
    std::cout << sizeof Automation::next_state_fn << std::endl; /* 32 */
    return 0;
}
```

Could anybody please tell me what's the proper way for that?

Comment: Why do you need `mem_fun` in the first place? Wouldn't `void (Automation::*)(int)` do? The task of `mem_fn` is to adapt member functions for callers that don't expect member functions, .e.g. `std::transform()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return type of `std::mem_fn` is unspecified by the standard, so there is no portable way to explicitly declare a member variable of that type.

Although the `decltype` construct might look strange, it's the correct way to go about this. `std::function` incurs some overhead, but is more flexible as you can pass it around much easier than when using the `decltype` version.